# How does Karel run without "main" method?

Tags: java, karel

I was wondering in the program like [Karel the Robot](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/handouts/H02.pdf) runs because it does not used main() method. Instead it used run() method:

```
import stanford.karel.Karel;

public class CollectNewspaperKarel extends Karel { 
  public void run() { 
    move(); 
  } 
}
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual main method is somewhere else. For example, in [the KarelRunner class](http://www.csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/KJRdocs/index.html). When java executes the program, it's actually executing the main method in the runner class. Your own run method is called from that runner code.

Answer (score 2):

a "main" method is the starting point of every java program. What is going on with this class is that its not a java program by itself, is executed inside some type of framework (karel robot java implementation in this case), this frameworks off course have a "main" method but not this class, the framework knows how to load this class and execute his run method.

This "programs" are frameworks designed to do a specialized type of programs, i don't know this "karel framework", but for example, when you program a java web application you write a "servlet" but you don't write a "main" method. There are some programs called "application servers" that off course have a "main" method and take this servlet class and execute for response to some http message.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing weird about it. The `CollectNewspaperKarel` class is just extending the behavior of Karel. **It doesn't need to have a `main` method.**

**The class that will be the entry point of the program does need** to have a `main` method and create an instance of `CollectNewspaperKarel`, like:

```
public class MyProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CollectNewspaperKarel cnpk = new CollectNewspaperKarel();
        cnpk.run();
    }
}
```

Or the instance of CollectNewspaperKarel could be a static field:

```
public class MyProgram {
    private static CollectNewspaperKarel cnpk = new CollectNewspaperKarel();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cnpk.run();
    }
}
```

**Karel is not an application, it's an API. You make the application.**

Answer (score 0):

When you read all of those instructions, you will discover that the program being run by Karel is a small part of a larger system -- the larger system involves drawing the map, discovering logic errors, etc.  You write things in `run()`, then you use one of the classes which actually runs the entire system, and one of THOSE calls `run()` on your program.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is quite simple: `extends Karel`

The `Karel` class is one that implements `Runnable`, and has quite a few methods within it.

Without trying to go into detail about what all it does, it looks something like this:

```
public class Karel implements java.lang.Runnable {
    private static final int NORTH = 0;
    private static final int EAST = 1;
    private static final int SOUTH = 2;
    private static final int WEST = 3;
    private static final int INFINITE = 99999999;
    private stanford.karel.KarelWorld world;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int dir;
    private int beepers;

    public Karel() { /* compiled code */ }
    public void run() { /* compiled code */ }
    public void move() { /* compiled code */ }
    public void turnLeft() { /* compiled code */ }
    public boolean beepersPresent() { /* compiled code */ }
    public boolean noBeepersPresent() { /* compiled code */ }
    public boolean beepersInBag() { /* compiled code */ }
    public boolean noBeepersInBag() { /* compiled code */ }
    public boolean facingNorth() { /* compiled code */ }
    public boolean facingEast() { /* compiled code */ }
    public boolean facingSouth() { /* compiled code */ }
    public boolean facingWest() { /* compiled code */ }

    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) { /* compiled code */ }
    protected void start() { /* compiled code */ }
    protected void start(java.lang.String[] args) { /* compiled code */ }

    ...
}
```

I took out quite a few methods from there because its a very long list of things it defines.

But ore that last one that I left in there... `protected void start(java.lang.String[] args)` (or at least, that's how my library inspector interpreted it).  <sup><sub>Digging into this code, it appears that this invokes `main()` in KarelProgram, but for the most part, thats neither here nor there.</sub></sup>

And thus you have inheritance.  You are inheriting a number of other methods that the code is using.  That you are using `move();` in that code but not defining it should be no more surprising than having a `main(java.lang.String[] args)` defined.

All it takes is opening up the class in the jar in your IDE.

Comment: what is inside the public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) { /* compiled code */ }?

Comment: Dunno, the viewpoint that I have for the method is complied byte code and there's an `invokestatic` in there. I really didn't bother looking in there too deeply and sources weren't attached in the .jar file.